# Relational Databases: Database Structure / Flow

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework to setup a database. I'm brand new to relational databases and I'm attempting to determine the proper way to setup a few tables and their relations. Here's the scoop.

Say I have three tables in my database.

The main table is table A which holds a dataset for an object let's call this object `Food`. Columns: `FoodID` (primary key), RecipeID (foreign key paired to it's recipe in Table C).

Table C : contains records for recipes used to make the different `Food` items stored in Table A. Columns: RecipeID (primary key) and Recipe Name.

Table B : Is an instruction / recipe entry to for creating a `Food`. Columns : EntryID (primary key), RecipeID (foreign key referencing the Recipe ID in table C), FoodID (foreign key referencing a Food in Table A).

I can't wrap my ahead around the proper way to do this since it makes a circular relationship.

Do I just remove the foreign key (`RecipeID`) from the `Food` table? What is the proper flow I should be pursuing in situations like this.

```
 Recipes -> Multiple Recipe Entries -> Food -> Recipe
```

`Food` requires a recipe to make it but `Food` is used in recipes to make other `Food`.

Conceptualizing the data into C# code it would look like this.

```
public class Food
{
    public int FoodID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Food> Recipe { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework Model would be the following.

```
public class Food
{
    [Key]
    public int FoodID { get; set; }//Pri Key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FoodRecipeID { get; set; }//Foreign Key

    public virtual FoodRecipe FoodRecipe { get; set; }//Navigation Property
}

public class FoodRecipeEntry
{
    [Key] 
    public int FoodRecipeEntryId { get; set; } //Pri Key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int FoodID { get; set; }//Foreign Key
    public int FoodRecipeID { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public Food Food { get; set; }
    public FoodRecipe FoodRecipe { get; set; }
}

public class FoodRecipe
{
    [Key]
    public int FoodRecipeID { get; set; } //Pri Key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FoodRecipeEntry> FoodRecipeEntries {get; set; }//Navigation Property
}
```

Comment: Whats the issue with a circular relationship? That sounds correct for your scenario. You just have to ensure your UI doesn't allow you to create an infinite loop.

Comment: I believe your model is conceptually correct - why are you questioning it?

Comment: I wasn't assuming it was wrong, I was just wondering what the preferred or generally accepted approach for this type of structure is. Like I said I'm brand new to databases. I appreciate the comments

Answer (score -1):

Here are some pointers:

1. Remove the Food ID from `FoodRecipeEntry`, the FoodID is implied by the recipe since the recipe is for a specific food, and the entry belongs to the given recipe
2. I'd personally put the foreign key inside Recipe, not Food - a single food may have multiple recipes, so it should be Recipe -> Food

In code this would look like so:

```cs
public class Food
{
    [Key]
    public int FoodID { get; set; }//Pri Key
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual FoodRecipe FoodRecipe { get; set; }//Navigation Property
}

public class FoodRecipeEntry
{
    [Key] 
    public int FoodRecipeEntryId { get; set; } //Pri Key
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FoodRecipe")] // Personally I prefer using explicit foreign key attributes to avoid implicit jankiness
    public int FoodRecipeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Ingredient")]
    public int IngredientID { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual FoodRecipe FoodRecipe { get; set; }


    public virtual Food Ingredient { get; set; }
}

public class FoodRecipe
{
    [Key]
    public int FoodRecipeID { get; set; } //Pri Key
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Food")] // Personally I prefer using explicit foreign key attributes to avoid implicit jankiness
    public int FoodID { get; set; }//Foreign Key
    public virtual Food Food { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FoodRecipeEntry> FoodRecipeEntries {get; set; }//Navigation Property
}
```

Comment: One assume that some food is primary/basic food, with no recipe, in which case the `FoodRecipeEntry` definitely needs  a `FoodID` property.

Comment: And I think you might have missed that point that a food item could have a single recipe to create it, but could be 1 of many food items in a recipe - hence I think the original keys are correct.

Comment: That's fair @DaleK though it really wasn't specified above, and if it is, I'd call that field IngredientId and Ingredient so it's not misleading. The above structure would still avoid the circular reference issue even then, and that's an even better reason not to have the recipe ID on the food object.

Comment: Naming aside, I think the circular reference is required, and is OK.

Comment: Just to Clarify, perhaps food was a bad analogy for a more complex data item. Food only has one recipe. That is why there is not a collection of recipes in the food class. I'm new to Databases so I wasn't sure if circular references were good pratice

Comment: Beyond the nitbits in the particular example, your structure is fine @Dammer15 In this case I'd only move the FK to the other end of the 1:1 relationship because Food seems like the base item.

Comment: On that note, use a nullable like `int?` for foreign keys that may not have an entity on the other end :).

Comment: The nullable int for the foreign key RecipeID inside the Food table makes a lot of sense with the circular referencing I have setup. Thanks for confirmations and suggestions guys. I'm leaving both FKs Food could be a base food like stated above with no Reciepe.